# pointer-events: none; doesn't work in IE

Tags: css

```
pointer-events: none;
```

This doesn't work in IE but works in Chrome, I need to disable checkboxes in IE, is there any way to disable checkboxes from CSS?

Answer (score 0):

try with js

```js
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('.wrapper input[type="checkbox"]').attr('disabled', true);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"><label>disabled input <input type="checkbox"></label></div>
```

Comment: My checkboxes are generated dynamically, not from front end, so there is no id or class for the chckboxes. Hence, i want to achieve it from CSS

Comment: ok)
$(window).load(function() {
  $('your parent  class name input[type="checkbox"]').attr('disabled', true);
});